# Multiple onchange effects in a for loop passing parameter

Tags: javascript, for-loop, parameters, onchange

I am trying to do a for-loop in javascript, in where I place an onChange function for every element in the loop/list. When the onChange triggers, the setValidation function should trigger with the correct parameter:

I've been trying the following code for now

```
var allConditions = document.getElementsByClassName("condition-container");

for (let i = 0; i < allConditions.length; i++) 
{
    document.getElementById("PropertyPre" + i).onchange = function () 
    {
        setValidation(false, i);
    }
};


function setValidation(firstTime, elementNumber) 
{
   console.log("This is number: " + elementNumber);
}
```

The actual output when I change something on the HTML element `PropertyPre0` is the following: `This is number 2`, but it actually should return `This is number 0`.

Is there anybody that has an idea how to fix the code?

Comment: Is PropertyPre0 the first or third element on the DOM with the class "condition-container" ?

Comment: It is the first one. Condition-container is the highest level dom element in a partial view. There can be one or multiple "Condition" partial views.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem here or on jsfiddle.net so we can see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed you have 3 div element with class "condition-container" and id "PropertPre" + i (depend on how many class u have)

```js
var allConditions = document.getElementsByClassName("condition-container");

for (let i = 0; i < allConditions.length; i++) 
{
    document.getElementById("PropertyPre" + i).onchange = function () 
    {
        return setValidation(false, i);
    };
};


function setValidation(firstTime, elementNumber) 
{
   console.log("This is number: " + elementNumber);
}
```

```html
<div class="condition-container">
<div class="condition-container">
<div class="condition-container">
<input id="PropertyPre0">
<input id="PropertyPre1">
<input id="PropertyPre2">
```